React Hotkeys does not have access to component's state
My goal is to perform an action when keyboard button is pressed, using current value of variable that I declared with useState.
I reproduced my problem in code example below:
import React from 'react';
import { HotKeys } from 'react-hotkeys';
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';

const keyMap = {
    MOVE_DOWN: 'a'
};

export function App(props) {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(0);

  const focusNextRow = useCallback(() => {
      console.log("test", test);
      setTest(test => test + 1);
      console.log("test2", test);
  }, [test]);

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log("TEST IS NOW ", test);
  }, [test]);

  const handlers = {
      MOVE_DOWN: focusNextRow
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <HotKeys keyMap={keyMap} handlers={handlers}>
        <div>test</div>
      </HotKeys>
    </div>
  );
}

Result looks like this:

As you can see: test value in component is updated, but method that is called on keyboard press has always default value of this state (which is 0). How can I fix that?

Your useCallback should not depend on test.  Don't include it among the dependencies with [test] (you can safely remove it).  Also, maybe rename the parameter to your lambda from test to prevTest and the semantics will be more clear to you.  Your log messages of test inside the useCallback are irrelevant and will only confuse you.  Remove them too.

to elaborate on why the logs in useCallback are not useful, as Wyck mentioned: you are getting all the info you need from the log in your useEffect.  it will tell you the state every time it changes.  using the setter will not IMMEDIATELY update the value, so a log on the next line will not be helpful.  the react docs cover this exact issue.

It appears that the HotKeys component does a bit of configuration memoization where it doesn't "listen" to updates to certain props.
You can use the allowChanges prop to let the HotKeys component react to  the handlers changes/updates. See Component Props API for details.

/**
 * Whether the keyMap or handlers are permitted to change after the
 * component mounts. If false, changes to the keyMap and handlers
 * props will be ignored
 *
 * Optional.
 */
allowChanges={false}


import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { HotKeys } from "react-hotkeys";
import "./styles.css";

const keyMap = {
  MOVE_DOWN: "a",
};

export default function App() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(0);

  const focusNextRow = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("test", test);
    setTest((test) => test + 1);
    console.log("test2", test);
  }, [test]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("TEST IS NOW ", test);
  }, [test]);

  const handlers = {
    MOVE_DOWN: focusNextRow,
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HotKeys keyMap={keyMap} allowChanges handlers={handlers}>
        <div>test</div>
      </HotKeys>
    </div>
  );
}

That said, this still leaves a basic stale Javascript closure problem where you are attempting to log the React state after enqueueing a state update. React state updates are processed asynchronously, so you can't ever log the state immediately after it's enqueued anyway. See The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately for full details.
The useEffect hook is the correct method for logging state updates.
If you wanted, you could log the "before" and "after" values in the state updater function
const focusNextRow = useCallback(() => {
  setTest((test) => {
    console.log("test", test);
    const nextTest = test + 1;
    console.log("test2", nextTest);
    return nextTest;
  });
}, []);

but since the state updater functions are to be considered pure functions this should generally be avoided. But it could be useful/handy as a debugging step.

In useCallback, do not add test as a dependency of the callback.
no:
  , [test]);

yes:
  , []);

I also suggest using a name like prevTest for the parameter of the lambda function you pass to setTest so that you are reminded that it is not the current value of test and does not use the same name as the useState hook. (test, and setTest are already defined in the enclosing scope.  It may be confusing to use test again here as the argument name.)
no:
   setTest(test => test + 1); // Careful! You already have a var named `test` in enclosing scope

yes:
   setTest(prevTest => prevTest + 1);

And finally, be careful about what you are logging.  It doesn't make sense to log the value of test after calling setTest because of the way react state hooks work.  See the documentation of useState. At this point I suggest just removing your log messages.
Final version:
  const focusNextRow = useCallback(() => {
    setTest(prevTest => prevTest + 1);
  }, []);


You shouldn't log anything in the lambda you pass to setTest.  It's a pure function and could technically be called at any time with any value so to log something like "previous value of test:", prevTest is wrong.  It doesn't reflect the current or previous state of anything.  But it does get called to derive the next state from the previous state.  But potentially multiple times.

Your unexpected behaviour seems to be coming from the usage of useCallback
Apparently, it is called Clusure Issue referenced in this question.
TL;DR

The Closure Issue The behavior you're seeing is related to JavaScript
closures and how React's hooks capture values. When useCallback
creates a memoized callback, it captures the value of state at the
time the callback is created. Even though you included state in the
dependency array, the cleanup function from useEffect runs with the
original closure that was created during the initial render. The
Timeline
Initial render: state is 0, callback is created capturing state = 0
useEffect runs: calls setState(1) Component re-renders: state is now 1
When component unmounts: cleanup function runs using the original
callback

